# Rails 4 - Customizing will_paginate page 2+

Tags: ruby-on-rails, will-paginate

My homepage has a big banner image, a featured item widget followed by "new products" which is all products sorted by create date. I have will_paginate on the all products section of the site. When I click on page 2, I only want product listings...I don't want the homepage banner and featured widget to be repeated on every page link. How would I do this?

Comment: only output the banner, etc. if `params[:page]` is nil or 1?

Comment: thanks! i should have figured that out.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it by set layout

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  layout :choose_layout

  def choose_layout
    if params[:page] < 2          
      "application"
    else
      "withoutbaneer"
    end
  end
 end
```

and use two layouts file `/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb` and `/app/views/layouts/withoutbanner.html.erb`